# Install Heimdall 1.4.2

Tags: 19.04, git, heimdall

The `heimdall-flash` package in the repos install Heimdall 1.4.1 but this doesn't work with my device.

How do I install version 1.4.2 on Ubuntu 19.04?

I tried downloading the source and compiling following instructions in [this file](https://gitlab.com/BenjaminDobell/Heimdall/tree/master/Linux), but I'm getting an error message

```
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/chris/Heimdall-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

This file doesn't have the word error in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to compile Heimdall from source. The error was due to a missing dependency.

This is how I installed it:

1. Download Heimdall from https://gitlab.com/BenjaminDobell/Heimdall/tree/v1.4.2
2. Unzip and cd into the Heimdall folder.
3. Install dependencies: `sudo apt install qt5-default libgl1-mesa-dev build-essential cmake zlib1g-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev`
4. Create build directory: `mkdir build`
5. cd into it: `cd build`
6. Run: `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
7. Run: `make`

Heimdall is now compiled and the binary is found in the `build/bin` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Struggled with the same problem and found an another way. You can try to find the `.deb` package for 1.4.2 somewhere in the net. However there seems not to be such to be found easily but `.rpm`s are, like [this](https://altlinux.pkgs.org/sisyphus/classic-x86_64/heimdall-1.4.2-alt1.x86_64.rpm.html) *(see the download section of that page)*.

So as a fallback solution there is an option to install it from `.rpm` package and for that you need to install [`alien`](https://wiki.debian.org/Alien) that can be used to convert `.rpm` to `.deb`.

```
sudo apt install alien
```

Then after downloading `.rpm` it is just like

```
sudo alien heimdall-1.4.2-alt1.x86_64.rpm
```

That should respond

> heimdall_1.4.2-1_amd64.deb generated

Then it is just to install

```
sudo dpkg -i heimdall_1.4.2-1_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got Heimdall 1.4.2 to work on my Linux Mint 19 xfce (64bit) machine.

To Do's solution, mine and the solution my post is based on (phd21 at this thread: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=266217) all refer back to the developer's instructions at: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/master/Linux/README, appendix B.

My suggested code, based on phd21's, contains a couple corrections. For example, the Heimdall project has since moved back to github from gitlab, and the 'git clone' instruction has been updated to reflect that move.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake git curl wget checkinstall zlib1g-dev qt5-default libusb-1.0-0-dev libusb-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dev libqt5x11extras5 libqt5x11extras5-dev

git clone https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall

cd Heimdall-master

mkdir build

cd build

cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..

sudo make

sudo make install
```

You run the software with:

```
heimdall-frontend
```